# How check if a circle is contained by any rectangle? (in pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

In my pygame I have a drawn a couple rectangles with a for loop. I have a player which is represented by a circle object. It looks like this:

[image]

So the player can move with arrow keys, this will move them one spot per key. Ultimately the player should not be able to move outside these rectangles. So each time they move I want to check:
If (any drawn rectangle contains a player): return True else return False.

Is there any easy way to do this? Or should I completely change my approach?

It should not be able to move on spots outside the rectangles like this:
[image]

but only in the rectangles like this:
[image]

This is the code of this example I have right now:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#grid
w = 25
h = 25
m = 2

size = (550, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 149
        self.y = 14
        self.r = 10

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.r)

    def update(self,event):
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                screen.fill((250, 250, 250))
                self.x -= 27
                self.draw()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                screen.fill((250, 250, 250))
                self.x += 27
                self.draw()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                screen.fill((250, 250, 250))
                self.y -= 27
                self.draw()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                screen.fill((250, 250, 250))
                self.y += 27
                self.draw()

player1 = Player()
player1.draw()

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player1.update(event)

        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if row == 0 or row == 4 or col == 0 or col == 4:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), ((w + m) * col + m, ((h + m) * row + m), w, h), 1)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

There is a *Rect.contains(Rect)* function but this checks it if one rectangle contains another rect. Is there maybe a function like this that basically says: select all existing Rectangles and check if they contain (chosen rect)?

Any tips or help is absolutely appreciated. Also let me know if this is a completely wrong approach to doing this whole thing.

Greetings.

Comment: `pygame.draw.circle` returns `python.Rect` object so you can treat `circle` as `rectangle`. Besides you can use `row`, `col` instead of `x`, `y` to check "collision".

Comment: BUT there is one small mistake in all your code - you don't keep positions  of all rectangles on list so you can't check they position with circle position.

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable you can keep all classes and functions before `pygame.init()` - see [simple template](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__templates__/1__simple__.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `circle` as `rectangle`. It needs less calculations (CPU power) to check collisions if you treat all objects as rectangles.

You have to create list with all rectangles so you could check circle position with this list - and then you can use `circle_rect.colliderect(some_rect)`

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

#grid
W = 25
H = 25
M = 2

SIZE = (550, 700)

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

FPS = 25
# --- classes ---

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        # to keep position and size
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)

        # set start position
        self.rect.center = 149, 14

        self.r = 10

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, self.rect.center, self.r)

    def update(self, event):
        # create copy of position
        newrect = self.rect.copy()

        # move "copy" to new position
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            newrect.x -= 27
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            newrect.x += 27
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            newrect.y -= 27
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            newrect.y += 27

        # check if "copy" is still in rectangles
        for rectangle in all_rectangles:
            if newrect.colliderect(rectangle):
                # now you can set new position
                self.rect = newrect
                # don't check other rectangles
                break

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

player1 = Player()

# create list with rectangles (but not draw them)

all_rectangles = []

for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        if row == 0 or row == 4 or col == 0 or col == 4:
            all_rectangles.append( pygame.Rect((W + M) * col + M, ((H + M) * row + M), W, H) )

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    
done = False

while not done:

    # - events (without draws) -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player1.update(event)


    # - draw everything in one place -

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    for rectangle in all_rectangles:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, rectangle, 1)

    player1.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS - keep the same speed on all computers -

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -
pygame.quit()
```

---

**BTW:** you could use `row`, `col` instead of `x`, `y` to keep rectangles positons and circle position (and check collisions) and only convert `row/col` to `x/y` when you draw it. You can also create list with rectangles like

```
all_rectangles = [
   "######",
   "#    #",
   "#    #",
   "#    #",
   "######",
]
```

and then it is easier to create map.

---

**EDIT:**

```
map = [
   "########  #######",
   "#      ####     #",
   "#      #  #     #",
   "#    ########   #",
   "######      #   #",
   "   #        #####",
   "   #          #  ",
   "   ############  ",
]

all_rectangles = []

for r, row in enumerate(map):
    for c, item in enumerate(row):
        if item == '#':
            all_rectangles.append(pygame.Rect((W + M) * c + M, ((H + M) * r + M), W, H))
```

[image]

Comment: After going it thoroughly I created a list with all position with all positions like you did to compare the move first before moving the player, my pygame is working exactly how I want it now!! Thanks you, I am forever grateful!!

Comment: @Noob17 see [other modifications](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/example-maze)